# How to use SKAudioNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skaudionode

I found out SKAction playSoundFileNamed does memory leak in IOS 9:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20014

They recommend to use SKAudioNode, but the example is swift and i use objective-c in my project.

Example:

```
func testAudioNode() {  
    let audioNode = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "LevelUp")  
    audioNode.autoplayLooped = false  
    self.addChild(audioNode)  
    let playAction = SKAction.play()  
    audioNode.runAction(playAction)  
}
```

What i have tried:

```
-(void)testSound{
testSound = [SKAudioNode nodeWithFileNamed:@"test.wav"];
testSound.autoplayLooped = false;
[self addChild:testSound];

SKAction *playaction = [SKAction play];

[testSound runAction:playaction];
}
```

It will crash to:

```
[self addChild:testSound];
```

So how i would get it work, what is good technique for play sounds with SKAudioNode only in IOS 9> and with SKAction in older versions?

Thanks!

Comment: It crashes because `testSound` is nil. You have to create SKAudioNode properly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `+ nodeWithFileNamed:` creates a new node by loading an archive file from the game’s main bundle. So you can't use it in this situation.

Try something like this (using [initWithFileNamed](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAudioNode/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKAudioNode/initWithFileNamed:) initializer):

```
#import "GameScene.h"

@interface GameScene()
@property (nonatomic, strong)SKAudioNode *testSound;
@end

@implementation GameScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view{

     self.testSound = [[SKAudioNode alloc] initWithFileNamed:@"test.wav"];
     self.testSound.autoplayLooped = false;
     [self addChild:self.testSound];
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

   [self.testSound runAction:[SKAction play]];

}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! Some reason your code is not working in my actual project, but i tested it in new(empty)project and it worked fine! It crash immediately when game scene loads...any doubts ?

Comment: @TeKo It works for me as well... You have to be more specific about the actual error.

Comment: it says:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: _engine->IsRunning()'

Comment: I got it fixed! Problem was playing a sound instantly after scene transition.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/27980#jive-2401624518966197692552

Thank you very much for the help!